# Is there a way to quick load in the same way you can quick save?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I am say... doing nefarious things, I often obsessively quick save, but then it is cumbersome, when my dirty deeds are discovered, that I have to open multiple menus to reload my save.  Is there a faster way to streamline my evil plans?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To quickload, use F9 on the PC.  (For reference, F5 is quicksave on the PC)

I don't believe the Xbox or PS3 versions have this button mapped, although there's indications that the upcoming Xbox Kinect support will add it as a voice command: